# How to connect CodeStriker to FogBugz

Tags: integration, fogbugz, scmbug

I have just installed the [CodeStriker](http://codestriker.sourceforge.net/) code review tool.
Has anyone attempted connecting it to FogBugz?
In the CodeStriker documentation I saw it works with [Scmbug](http://freshmeat.net/projects/scmbug/), whichintegrates software configuration management (SCM) with bug-tracking.
Has anyone connected Scmbug to FogBugz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I now have a partial answer:

1. Let FOGBUGZSERVER be the machine where fogbugz is installed. In the codestriker.conf file under /var/www/codestriker/codestriker-x.y.z Redefine the $bugtracker variable as:

`$bugtracker = 'http://FOGBUGZSERVER/fogbugz/default.asp?';`

2. Rerun install.pl
3. Restart the apache server.

Now when you insert a case id in the topic information, you will get a link to the proper fogbugz case.

Answer (score 1):

We haven't heard of anyone doing so at Fog Creek.  You might also ask at http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com.